# Application of differentiation (Rectangular box)

Tags: calculus

A rectangular block with a square base and height $2(a-x)$,$x<a$, is inscribed in a sphere of fixed radius $a$ such that the vertices of the block just touch the interior of the sphere.

a)Show that the square base has side length $\sqrt{2x(2a-x)}$.  Hence, write down the volume of the block in terms of $x$ and $a$.

b)Show that the volume of the block is largest when it's a cube.  Hence, find the volume of the cube in terms of $a$.

My attempt, 
Let $l$ be the length of rectangular box.
$$a^2=(a-x)^2+(\frac{l}{2})^2$$
$$a^2=(a^2-2ax+x^2)+\frac{l^2}{4}$$
$$4(2ax-x^2)=l^2$$
$$l=2\sqrt{x(2a-x)}$$

I cannot show the answer which is $\sqrt{2x(2a-x)}$, any mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the first equation you wrote. In the diagram, you can see that the triangle formed with the center of the sphere and one of the vertices of the rectangular prism has a leg along the *diagonal* of the base, not one of its edges.

[image: sphere and prism diagram]

The correct equation should therefore be

$$a^2=(a-x)^2+\left(\frac{l\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2$$